Glup/Rollup/babel-preset-minify requires await on rollup.rollup() for multiple files in same function
I want to verify that the statement in the title is true, and see if anyone can provide an explanation and/or a workaround. If I only work with one .js file, it works without the async/await. Adding the second file causes the error.  I have tried using bundle.close() at the end of each .then(), but that makes no difference, probably because this is a babel-preset-minify issue at its core. I know that because removing this line from my babel.config.json avoids the error:
  "presets": [["minify", {"builtIns":false}]],

I am already considering switching to Terser, as this is the second issue I've had to workaround with babel-preset-minify. This is my first automated javascript build, so I'm just getting to know all of these tools. It's not as if this project is very large, but I'd prefer not to use async/await everywhere if I don't have to.
This gulpfile.js works:
const
{parallel} = require("gulp"),
 rollup    = require("rollup"),
 babel     = require("@rollup/plugin-babel");

async function build(cb) {
  // File 1:
  await rollup.rollup({
    input: "multi-check.js",
    plugins: [babel({ babelHelpers: "bundled" })]
  })
  .then(bun => bun.write({
    file: "dist/check-box.js",
    format: "es"
  }));
  // File 2:
  await rollup.rollup({
    input: "multi-button.js",
    plugins: [babel({ babelHelpers: "bundled" })]
  })
  .then(bun => bun.write({
    file: "dist/state-btn.js",
    format: "es"
  }));
  cb();
}

exports.build = build;
exports.default = parallel(build);

This gulpfile.js throws Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getCode') at NodePath.getSource (C:\Apache24\htdocs\html-elements\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\introspection.js:137:27). The only difference between the two gulpfiles is the addition of async/await:
const
{parallel} = require("gulp"),
 rollup    = require("rollup"),
 babel     = require("@rollup/plugin-babel");

function build(cb) {
  rollup.rollup({
    input: "multi-check.js",
    plugins: [babel({ babelHelpers: "bundled" })]
  })
  .then(bun => bun.write({
    file: "dist/check-box.js",
    format: "es"
  }));
  rollup.rollup({
    input: "multi-button.js",
    plugins: [babel({ babelHelpers: "bundled" })]
  })
  .then(bun => bun.write({
    file: "dist/state-btn.js",
    format: "es"
  }));
  cb();
}

exports.build = build;
exports.default = parallel(build);

